# How to keep track of the object reference in a useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building some API hooks and I have trouble with `deps` property. I want to reinvoke the `useEffect` when content of `deps` changes, instead I'm running in a forever loop. `deps` can be either undefined or an `any[]`

```
export const useReader = <TResponseData>({ url, deps, options }: TypeUseReader<TResponseData>) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState<TResponseData | null>(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState<number | null >(null);

    async function fetchData(newUrl?: string) {}

    useEffect(() => {
       // ..fetch
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [url, deps]); // HERE, deps are forever loop

    return {
        data,
        isLoading,
        error,
        fetchData
    };
};
```

That's how I'm using it:

```
 return useReader<FOO>(
        {
            url: 'URL_PLACEHOLDER',
            deps: [anything] /* FIXME: deps enters FOREVER LOOP */
        }
    );
```

What I have tried:

`[deps ?? []]` and `...[deps ?? []]` and `deps` - all of these create forever loop

Comment: Did you try replacing `[options?.deps ?? []]`  as a dependency in `useEffect` with: `options` ? I suspect that wrapping the entire thing with an array causes it to re-evaluate to a new object every time it's being checked.

Comment: @NirAlfasi I switched to using `deps` directly to remove `options` prop from the equation and updated the code. But I still get forever loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you're calling `useReader` with `deps` as an array literal, a new array is being created each time, so `useEffect` rightly detects a change in the value.

Broadly speaking, there are two ways to deal with this.

You can make it the responsibility of the caller – specify in the `useReader` interface that it accepts a single `dep` value of `unknown` type. If the caller wants to pass through an array of values, then these should be stabilized, e.g.

```js
const dep = useMemo(() => [val1, val2], [val1, val2]);
return useReader<FOO>(
        {
            url: 'URL_PLACEHOLDER',
            isSuspended: false,
            initialValue: foo,
            dep   /* only changes if val1 or val2 has changed */
        }
    );
```

Easier and more flexible is to accept an array of `deps` (typed as `unknown[]`), and just spread the members of the array after the other dependencies you're passing to `useEffect`:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!isSuspended) {
            fetchData();
        }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [isSuspended, url, ...(deps ?? [])]);
```

The various linters do get upset about this, but it's not problematic as far as the hook machinery is concerned.

Comment: Thanks. This works! Now I see clearly why it had a forever loop, I was creating a new array each time. But why `...(deps ?? [])` is not causing a forever loop too ? Destructuring is returning a new value.. OR is it because Destructuring doesn't change the references?

Comment: You haven't shared the definition of `TypeUseReader<TResponseData>`, so I'm not sure if you're treating `deps` as optional. If `deps` is undefined then `deps ?? []` will just fall back to an empty array. Spreading an empty array doesn't affect the contents of the `useEffect` dependencies, and it's only the contents that determine if the effect is re-run. If you're requiring `deps` as a param to `useReader` then you can just use `...deps` instead of `...(deps ?? [])`

Comment: `deps` is optional, but if I understood your explanation correctly. That is not a problem because spreading an empty array has no effect on `useEffect` dependency array.

Comment: Your understanding is correct (or at least my understanding of your understanding :-)